# How to: Run a user defined function for a range of (date) values

Tags: azure-data-explorer

So let’s say I want to test a function that finds outliers over past data. I’d love to end up with a table that looks like this:

```
Time                    Outliers_At_Time
<somedate>              0
<somedate + interval>   1
```

The function looks like this:

```
let OutliersAt = (TheDate:datetime) {
<… outputs zero or a positive integer>
}
```

My instinct would be to do something like this:

```
let SomeDates = range AtTime from ago(10d) to now() step 10m;
SomeDates | extend NumOutliers = OutliersAt (AtTime)
```

… but that gives me this error message:

> Error Semantic error: '' has the following semantic error: Unresolved
>   reference binding: 'AtTime'. clientRequestId:
>   KustoWebV2;1ea28ba0-12f1-4a52-95e7-975db3310f59

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking on finding outliers - there is a built-in function in Kusto to do it: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/series-outliersfunction

Example:

```
let _data =
range Timestamp from ago(7d) to now() step 1min
    | extend Value=case(rand(1000)==10, 1200.0, rand(100));
// 
_data 
| make-series AvgValue=avg(Value) default=0 on Timestamp in range(ago(7d), now(), 5min) 
| extend outliers=series_outliers(AvgValue)
| render timechart
```

If the question is about general way to provide parameters to user-defined functions, 
see more info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions

In particular, you can pass a serie into a user-defined-function (e.g. to get statistics):

```
let OutliersAt = (_serie:dynamic) {
   let stats = series_stats_dynamic(_serie);
   todouble(stats.max_idx) >= 0 
};
let _data =
    range Timestamp from ago(7d) to now() step 1min
    | extend Value=case(rand(1000)==10, 1200.0, rand(100));
//
_data 
| make-series AvgValue=avg(Value) default=0 on Timestamp in range(ago(7d), now(), 5min) 
| extend outliers=series_outliers(AvgValue)
| project hasOutliers=OutliersAt(outliers)
```